# How to get categories ordered by displayName with Google My business API

Tags: javascript, rest, google-my-business-api

does the Google API provide a way to get the categories ordered by **displayName** or do I have to order them on my end?

Comment: Have you checked my answered? so you could close with a resolution for the next one to  see that the question is answer already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to order them as you need after getting the data. I have never found a sort query param to apply.